# How to default a column with value of a colunm of other table when create a new table?

Tags: oracle, default, ddl

```
CREATE TABLE "Family" (
  "Family_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  "Name" TEXT(20) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE "Babygirl" (
  "Baby_Id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "Family_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "Family_Name" TEXT(20) NOT NULL default......,
  "Last_Name" TEXT(20) NOT NULL,
);
```

how i write the sql of **default** after **Family_name** user the value of the **Name** of **Family** table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't (not as DEFAULT). If you already have a foreign key to the family table you don't need the name on the Babygirl table. When you need it just join the two tables in a simple sql statement.

Also don't use double quotes on your table names and column names. It will be hard to write sql statements to it.

Something like:

```
select f.columnsFromFamily, 
       b.columnsFromBabyGirl -- this is just an example
  from Family f
        inner join Babygirl b ON f.Family_ID = b.Family_ID
```

If you chose this approach drop the `Family_Name` column from `Babygirl` table.

The only thing you can do as you want (DUPLICATING the name) is to have a trigger to do so. Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ON trg_Babygirl
     BEFORE INSERT 
     ON Baygirl
as
DECLARE
   vFamilyName Family.Name%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
     select Name INTO vFamilyName 
       from Family
      where Family_id = :NEW.Family_ID;
      --set the name here
      :NEW.Family_Name := vFamilyName;
END;
```

I strongly discourage this approach. Just stick to the Foreign Key.

Comment: if use a foreign Key,when update the value of **name** of the **family** table,then the **family_name** will updated too,right?I need the value of **family_name** can separate from the **name** of family,only use a init value from it.for example,if a girl marry to a man,so she will change her family name,but name of her family,will not change.

Comment: can i default it like this:<code>Family_Name varchar(20) NOT NULL default(select name from family where family.family_id = babygirl.family_id )(/code)?thx!

Comment: The thing is if you use the foreign key, as I said, you don't have to have the column family_name on table `Babygirl` you only need the `name` column from the table `Family` having a foreign key you don't need to update at all the family name ti will be update on the `Family` table. As example Imagine you have `family( 1- Smiths; 2- McAdams)` and on the `BabyGirl( 1, 1(family_id), 'someLastName' )` You don't need to have `Smiths` on this registry because it is already tied with the `family_id 1` so if you need to change the name smiths you only change if on family table, the id will be same...

Comment: Therefore you will not need to change anything on the babygirl table. And if you need to change completely the name (create a new one) you just add another registry on family and update the family_id on babygirl table. Read about [Foreign Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) so you will understand it better.

Comment: And for your second comment: No you can't! Default values only accept constant values.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)